# Tagging in all SQL Databases in AZURE

Tags: azure, powershell, tags

I am trying to Tag in all of the SQL Database in Azure Server.
Trying using below two methods, but its not successful.

```
**Method 1**
$tags = @{"DBType"="Buy"; "DocumentTeam"="Common";"ResourceType"="SQL Database";"ProjectName"="Project"}
New-AzTag -ResourceId /subscriptions/6fd7cdd5-6985-409b-a9ec-0a733b802ad6/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/BuyServer/databases | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*_Report'} | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*_Time'} | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*MASTER'} -Tag $tags


**Method 2**
$tags = @{"DBType"="Buy"; "DocumentTeam"="Common";"ResourceType"="SQL Database";"ProjectName"="Project"}
$RESOURCE=Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" | Where-Object name -Like 'Europe*' | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'smartgepuateu*' } | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*_Report'} | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*_Time'} | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*MASTER'}
#Write-Output $RESOURCE
new-AzTag -Name    $RESOURCE.Name -Tag $tags
```

With Method 2, I got below error.
New-AzTag : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. 
Specified method is not supported.

With Method 1 : I did not received any output

Please help on this. Is there any other methods to tag all the SQL Databases in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution.

You can use foreach loop to tag all your databases.

Below is the sample code.

```
Clear-Host
$tags = @{"DBType"="OLTP"; "ProjectName"="Project"}
$RESOURCE=Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"| Where-Object name -Like 'ServerName*' |  Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*MASTER'}
$id=$RESOURCE.Id
foreach($thisid in $id){
Write-Output $thisid
new-AzTag -ResourceId  $thisid -Tag $tags
}
```